# How to create dynamic multiple grid regarding product attribute set

Tags: magento2

I have a requirement to create a multiple grids in a page on behalf of the attribute set.

Ex: 
Jeans(Attribute Set)
Id  Sku Name    Qty Image
1   test1   Test product    3   image.jpg

Gloves
Id  Sku Name    Qty Image
2   test2   Test product 2  3   image.jpg